# After apt install: Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: apt, mysql, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I run `apt install mysql-server` to install mysql, but it stuck (cursor blinking, no output), so I cancelled it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

After that, every command returned "Transport endpoint is not connected", like `shutdown`, `apt`, `systemctl`.

[shutdown not connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlOru.png)
[apt install not connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhip6.png)
[systemctl not connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNqtR.png)
[apt upgrade not connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib0uI.png)

I tried `wsl --shutdown` and rebooted my windows, but it didn't work.
How can i fix that problem?